# How can I get my CSOM code to authenticate using Windows Credentials when FBA is in use?

Tags: forms-authentication, client-object-model

The title should really say it all:

- Web Application with both Windows (NTLM) and FBA
- CSOM and REST requests are both failing with 403 (Forbidden)
- ClientContext.AuthenticationMode set to "Default" (there is no "force windows auth" option)
- SPClaimsAuthRoleProvider is the default provider in IIS

If I remove FBA then all my API calls start working. Any ideas?